# Creating a login page with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, authentication, logout

I am trying to make a webpage where a user logs in and then once logged in, the page keeps track of the amount of time idle (not pressing keys or moving mouse). I have created both pages separately on codepen (see attached links). However, I am not sure how to link the two so that the user can login and after waiting too long automatically log out.

Login page:
http://codepen.io/joebob461/pen/MwdPzN

```
 //incomplete code sample from link
function check(form) { 
  if (form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd") {
     window.open('target.html') 
  } else {
  alert("Error Password or Username") 
 }
}
```

Idle Time page:
http://codepen.io/joebob461/pen/BNeqvP

```
//incomplete code sample from link
#welcome {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You do not do login pages purely client-side. If this is just for learning, set a cookie on login and  use `location.href` to go to the new page, which you delete on logout or timeout. You cannot do it on different browser tabs.

Comment: What is your question basically?? is it something to do with create HTML page or is it how to track session timeout functionality???

Comment: It is more to do the tracking session timeout functionality. I got my 2nd page on codepen to track idleness and "timeout" but i don't know how to log out and go to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to post the login form data back to the server to authenticate.  The form post will redirect you to the second page with the idletimer javascript method.

Once the idletimer code determines it is time to log the user out, you can use an ajax post back to your server to have the server do this.  You haven't specified what server framework you are using.  However, in ASP.NET when using the ASP.NET Membership provider, you would just have the server call

```
FormsAuthentication.Signout()
```

Comment: as far as I know,  I don't have a server. I am only using codepen's free account. I'm also not entirely sure where to put the FormsAuthentication.Signout() method.

Comment: OK. so this is just for sample coding.  You should never authenticate a user's credentials on the client side.  It looks like you are not using a server mechanism to say the user is logged in, therefore you would want to use a cookie as one of the other posters mentioned.  You can then just delete that cookie when the user should be logged out per your "IdleTimeout" method.  The FormsAuthentication.Signout() is not applicable to your situation.